# Weak Parallelisability/Strong Orientability

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, orientation

An orientable manifold is defined by looking at small patches, looking at the interaction of local homology groups on these small patches, and focusing on when this gives us a coherent global story. If the manifold is differentiable, we can define parallelisability, choosing a basis for the tangent space which changes smoothly, which obviously implies orientability, but is stronger for differentiable manifolds. Here are some in-between conditions: $n$-manifold $M$ admits a continuous map $f:M\times S^{n-1}\to M$ such that, at all $p\in M$, $f[\{p\}\times S^{n-1}]$ corresponds to a generator of the local homology group at $p$ (as its boundary). $M$ admits a continuous map $f:M\times B^n\to M$ such that $f:(p,0)\mapsto p$, and, at all $p\in M$, $f[\{p\}\times B^n]$ corresponds to a generator of the local homology group at $p$, with $(p,q)=p$ implying $q=0$. Are these just restatements of orientability?

Comment: Do you mean the notation you have put in quotes itself, or how it corresponds to a generator?

Comment: I suspect that (1) is equivalent to the tangent sphere bundle being fiber homotopically trivial (which is much stronger than being orientable) and probably similarly for (2).